# How can I maximize the value of Appearance for a sidhe?

Tags: world-of-darkness, changeling-the-dreaming

I am preparing a character for my first Changeling:The Dreaming second edition game. I've opted for a sidhe, which come with this ability:

> Sidhe get two extra dots of Appearance during character creation, even if this increases scores above 5.

Starting with an attribute of 7 sounds pretty incredible, so I'd like to maximize the value of my Appearance. I'm having some trouble:

- I don't see any attributes which obviously synergize with my high Appearance.
- None of the Arts in the core rules are based on Appearance.
- The only task I've seen which calls for Appearance is seduction.

How can I maximize the value of my abnormally high Appearance score? Assume nothing about the rest of the party (our characters will meet for the first time at the table). Anything published for Changeling: The Dreaming second edition is allowed, but I myself was only able to search the core rules.

Comment: Consider rephrasing title. Reading it I got the impression that what you mean is "how to increase number of dots". Changing it to something like "increase number of ways to use appearance" would better communicate what you want.

Comment: Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/85071/how-to-play-appearance-straight-and-right

Answer (score 3):

### And now you know why it's free.

In Second Edition *Changeling*, as with many of the older World of Darkness titles, the use of Appearance is irregular and not well codified. The primary benefit is as a "permission" — if you have a 7 Appearance, the character is understood to be more compelling, more beautiful, more attractive than any human can be, and that has concomitant effects on the fiction.

Appearance is the "Wits" of the Social Skills; you use it early on, before the situation is settled and the person you're dealing with has a chance to respond with their brain rather than their heart, guts, or other parts. (In the 20th Anniversary rules set, Appearance serves as a cap on Social rolls "when first impressions are vital, or in situations where Appearance is valued."—C20, p.161)

So, to maximize your Appearance dots, put yourself in situations where your fantastic good looks give you the drop on people in social situations. Be forward and outgoing, and not afraid to stun people with fast talk. ("Give 'em the ol' razzle dazzle," as the song goes.)

However, when it comes to hard system support, you're largely on your own. As a sidhe, your real mechanical benefit comes from your House, not your kith.

Comment: +1. This is what I'm seeing also. I don't know if the headline is meaningful though. The sidhe benefit definitely isn't free.

Comment: “Free” in the sense that you don’t pay for those two dots of Appearance. Opportunity cost is always a factor.

Comment: Keep in mind also that this could be a hindrance. You are likely to be approached by people you may not wish to talk to or have nothing to do with the story. You are so exceedingly beautiful that you may cause people fear you due to their own inadequacies. You may cause people to question their sexuality. And, you are going to have a hell of a time trying to sneak anywhere. Be prepared to deal with sycophants and simps